# How to set string in currency format to normal number format?

Tags: iphone, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

How to set string in currency format to normal number format in iphone? i have a number in currency format say "Rs 10,000" or "$ 1000,000".now i am saving this in my database as a string in normal number format like "10000" or "1000000" ..so how to convert it to this form.. because only with the latter string i can use [string intValue] for use in calculations

Comment: Could you give an example, to be sure that answerers can understand what you mean exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using a NSNumberFormatter to set the currency style according to the locale? If so just extract it as a NSNumber object:

```
NSDecimalNumber *currencyAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"100.00"];

NSNumberFormatter *currency = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currency setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[currency setLocale:yourLocale];


NSString *yourstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [currency stringFromNumber:someAmount];

NSNumber* number = [currency numberFromString:yourString];
```